# find out id's of the correlating answers given using r

Tags: r

I have a  dataset with a few thousand entries.
every respondent is tagged with an id
i wanted to know the first ten respondents whom answered with  "Investigation complete; no suspect identified" so i created a vector and identified the first 10 entries of "Investigation complete; no suspect identified".

this  is the code i used to create the vector and it works just fine.

```
x<-0 
i <- 1
while (x <= 9) { 
  if  (crimes$outcome_status_category[i] %in% "Investigation complete; no suspect identified") {
    x <- x+1 
    no_sus[x] <- crimes$outcome_status_category[i]
  }
  i <- i +1
}
```

**Problem** :i am trying to figure out which respondent id's correlate to the first 10 entries of "Investigation complete; no suspect identified". it is mandatory that i use if-statements and while-loops but i have no clue how to do this. this is the code i tried

```
for( "Investigation complete; no suspect identified" in no_sus){
  print (crimes$id)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyaOM.jpg this is my dataset for refrence

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using `while` and `if` you can change the code to

```
x<-0 
i <- 1
no_id <- numeric(10)
while (x <= 9) { 
  if  (crimes$outcome_status_category[i] %in% "Investigation complete; no suspect identified") {
    x <- x+1 
    no_id[x] <- crimes$id[i]
  }
  i <- i +1
}
```

However, as most of the cases you don't need to explicitly use loops in R, you could also do :

```
result <- head(crimes$id[crimes$outcome_status_category %in% "Investigation complete; no suspect identified"], 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do regular subseting and you get a dataframe with all the rows that meet your criteria of `outcome_status_category` and then you can just extract the vector of ids.

```
df <- crimes[crimes$outcome_status_category == "Investigation complete; no suspect identified", ]  # extract dataframe with rows that match the criteria 
df$id               # extract ids 
df$id[1:10]         # extract first 10 ids
```